# AWS EC2 when deleted or terminated instance will be recreate again on instance type: t2.micro, What shall I do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I cannot delete or terminated instance forever in AWS EC2 instance with t2.micro
 instance type. It will recreating after a few minutes when the old deleted or terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because that your instance is part of an autoscaling group. You need to disable/delete that.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-enter-exit-standby.html

Comment: Okay, I will try and change it, Thanks!